# Which are the main aluminium alloys used in airliner construction?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerospace-materials, plane-construction

The proportion of composites used in airliner construction has increased in the last decades, with the B787 and the A350 being the first ones with composites making up the majority of wing and fuselage structure. From Wikipedia:

> The 787 is the first major commercial airplane to have a composite fuselage, composite wings, and use composites in most other airframe components.

And

> The A350 XWB airframe will be made out of 53% composites: carbon fibre reinforced plastic for the outer and centre wing box (covers, stringers, spars), fuselage (skin, frame, keel beam, and rear fuselage) and the empennage (horizontal and vertical tailplanes).

The vast majority of aircraft in operation (A320, A330, B737, B777) still use aluminium as the main load bearing construction material though. Which aluminium alloys were used for the wings and fuselage of these aircraft?

Comment: The alloys have different characteristics , so the answers also depend on which particular application.

Answer (score 6):

2000s, 6000s, and 7000s series alloy are very common for aircraft construction over the past 8 decades of metal aircraft design.  Boeing aircraft are largely manufactured from 2000s series aluminum alloy.