# Which aluminium alloy is used in the Boeing 747's fuselage?

Tags: boeing-747, fuselage, aerospace-materials

Which aluminium alloy is used in the Boeing 747's fuselage?

Comment: I will, Thanks.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47035/62)

Answer (score 4):

The primary alloy for the original 747 is 2024-T3, which is not the strongest or otherwise perfect, but a well-established convenient choice. Second is 7075-T6, used for major load-bearing parts.

7075 is stronger, but less workable and less tough than most; it comes closer to the edge for aluminum, so to speak. 
6061 follows for for less-loaded or some more complex parts, where it's a staple, being overall the easiest to use out of common Al alloys. This is not *nearly* an exhaustive list, just the main alloys.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple alloys are used. Here is a recycling composition breakdown of this aircraft, not specific to the fuselage:

[image]

[Materials of Civilian Aircraft](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&ved=0ahUKEwjG3rWi_KPbAhUMrVkKHVuGCf8QFgiEATAN&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2313-4321%2F2%2F4%2F21%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw1Cnjw40FykROLHb2r8DiVo)